# Angular 2 Material - text area text not prepopulating

Tags: angular-material2

I have a simple material style textarea that I prepopulate with data. However, the textarea will show the placeholder superscript as if there is text the text doesnt show until you start to type. Example:

```
 <md-form-field>
    <textarea
        formControlName="description"
        mdInput
        mdTextareaAutosize
        minRows="5"
        maxRows="10"
        placeholder="Write a comment...">
    </textarea>
  </md-form-field>
```

My textareas before you start to type:

[image]

My textareas after you type:

[image]

I tried to replicate this in [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJgvUu?p=preview) but I couldnt. What could cause this issue?

Comment: Can you share the relevant component class code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Material textarea is not pupulated. The solution for me was to not use the `mdTextareaAutosize` directive. Intsead I used the basic html one. So my code is the following:

```
<md-input-container style="width: 100%">
    <textarea 
        rows="4" 
        cols="50"
        mdInput 
        placeholder="Comment" 
        [formControl]="contentControl" 
        [(ngModel)]="commentDTO.content">
    </textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

Like this the text area is pre populated and works as expected. Hope it helps!